# How do I move an element in XSLT if it exists

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've been tasked with tidying up some XML so despite a rather loose DTD, everything is declared in the same way. For example, in the elements below

```
<all>
<e>
    <hg>
        <hw>things</hw>
        <posg><pos value="abc" /></posg>
    </hg>
    <sg><se1 /></sg>
</e>
<e>
    <hg>
        <hw>stuff</hw>
        <posg><pos value="def" /></posg>
    </hg>
    <sg>
        <se1>
            <posg><pos value="ghi" /></posg>
        </se1>
    </sg>
</e>
</all>
```

the `<posg>` element should be a child of `<se1>` and not `<hg>`. Furthermore, if a `<posg>` element already exists in the `<se1>` element, then I should create a new `<se1>` element as the first child of `<sg>` and then move the `<posg>` element from `<hg>` to the new `<se1>` element.

In effect then, the two elements above should look like this after transformation

```
<all>   
    <e>
        <hg>
            <hw>things</hw>
        </hg>
        <sg>
            <se1>
                <posg><pos value="abc" /></posg>
            </se1>
        </sg>
    </e>
    <e>
        <hg>
            <hw>stuff</hw>
        </hg>
        <sg>
            <se1>
                <posg><pos value="def" /></posg>
            </se1>
            <se1>
                <posg><pos value="ghi" /></posg>
            </se1>

        </sg>
    </e>
</all>
```

I have been struggling with how to check whether the rogue `<posg>` element exists within `<hg>` and then take the appropriate action described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="sg">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="../hg/posg">
        <se1><xsl:copy-of select="../hg/posg"/></se1>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="se1/posg">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="hg/posg"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: This solution works except that it will add in an extra se1 child to sg even if there is no posg to copy across from the hg element. How do you stop that happening or delete the generated empty se1 element?

Comment: No problem. I wrapped `<se1><xsl:copy-of .../></se1>` with `<xsl:if test="../hg/posg">`
and `</xsl:if>` (look in the script). Thus `<se1>` tag is generated only if there is something to put inside.